# Keep player moving when a voice command is said

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, grammar

I am trying to make a simple voice command game using GrammarRecognizer. I have managed to get the player to move left or right when the corresponding word is said.

I am trying to get the player to move continuously in one direction until the opposite word is said.

I have tried using a while loop but it seems to crash the program.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Please see the player controller code below:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;  // for stringbuilder
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Windows.Speech;   // grammar recogniser

public class PlayerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
   private GrammarRecognizer gr;
   public Rigidbody2D playerRb;

    private void Start(){
        playerRb = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>(); 
        gr = new GrammarRecognizer(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/SimpleGrammar.xml", ConfidenceLevel.Medium);
        gr.OnPhraseRecognized += GR_OnPhraseRecognized;
        gr.Start();
        Debug.Log("Grammer loaded and recogniser started");

    }
    private void GR_OnPhraseRecognized(PhraseRecognizedEventArgs args)
    {
        StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
        SemanticMeaning[] meanings = args.semanticMeanings;

        
            foreach(SemanticMeaning meaning in meanings)
            {
                string keyString = meaning.key.Trim();
                //Get meanings
                string valueString = meaning.values[0].Trim();
                //output phrase
                message.Append("Key: " + keyString + ", Value: " + valueString );
                //if left is said
                if(valueString == "left"){
                    //move left
                    transform.Translate(new Vector3(-200 * Time.deltaTime,0,0));
                    //transform.Translate(new Vector3(-200 * Time.deltaTime,0,0));
                }
                
                //if right is said
                if(valueString == "right"){
                    //move right
                    transform.Translate(new Vector3(200 * Time.deltaTime,0,0));
                    
                
                }

            }

        Debug.Log(message);

    }

    
    private void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        if(gr != null && gr.IsRunning)
        {
            gr.OnPhraseRecognized -= GR_OnPhraseRecognized;
            gr.Stop();
        }

       
    }

}
```

Please see my Grammar XML file below:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<grammar xml:lang="en" root="rightorleft"
tag-format="semantics/1.0" version="1.0"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/06/grammar">

  <rule id="rightorleft">
    <one-of>
      <item>
        <ruleref uri="#right"/>
      </item>
      <item>
        <ruleref uri="#left"/>
      </item>
    </one-of>
  </rule>

  <rule id="left">
    <item>left</item>
  </rule>

  <rule id="right">
    <item>right</item>
  </rule>

</grammar>
```

Comment: Never knew Unity even had this but `GR_OnPhraseRecognized` is a callback and so it will only move once.  Second, once a voice command is recognized in the `foreach` loop, you should `continue`, stop checking.  You probably want to start a Coroutine when a phrase is recognized or do something in `Update`.  Right now `Time.deltaTime` effectively means nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the help man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well instead of doing it only once store the last result and do e.g.

```
private enum Direction
{
    Idle,
    Left,
    Right
}

private Direction currentDirection;

private void Update()
{
    switch(currentDirection)
    {
        case Direction.Left:
            transform.Translate(Vector3.right * -200 * Time.deltaTime);
            break;

        case Direction.Right:
            transform.Translate(Vector3.right * 200 * Time.deltaTime);
            break;
    }
}

private void GR_OnPhraseRecognized(PhraseRecognizedEventArgs args)
{
    var message = new StringBuilder();
    var meanings = args.semanticMeanings;
    
    foreach(var meaning in meanings)
    {
        var keyString = meaning.key.Trim();
        var valueString = meaning.values[0].Trim();

        message.Append($"Key: {keyString}, Value: {valueString}");
        
        switch(valueString) 
        {
            case "left":
                currentDirection = Direction.Left;
                break;
            
            case "right":
                currentDirection = Direction.Right;
                break;
        }
    }

    Debug.Log(message);
}
```